# SSRS-Data Retrieval Failed for SubReport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report that is giving me this error:Data retrieval failed for the
Subreport...  This report has worked in the past.  In fact, it worked 2 days ago and I exported the results with no problem.  I have rebuild this subreport, checked that I was not passing null values. I have run with the same parameters that I did 2 days ago and it is erroring.  I have checked the parameter types.  Any ideas?

Comment: Will the report run on its own?

Comment: I found the issue.  There was a data change in the table that I query off of.  I was unaware of it and the change actually caused a divide by zero error.

Comment: Answer it and mark it as answered so it goes into the answered section.